# Installed EmojiOne, now entirety of Firefox is in serif font

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, firefox

I'm not quite sure what's going on here..

I installed the [EmojiOne Color SVGinOT Font](https://github.com/eosrei/emojione-color-font) from their [Github](https://github.com/eosrei/emojione-color-font) page because I was tired of black & white emojis on Ubuntu, but must have made a grave error because now the entirety of Firefox is displaying only Serif font.

I ran these commands:

```
# 1. Download the latest version
wget https://github.com/eosrei/emojione-color-font/releases/download/v1.3/EmojiOneColor-SVGinOT-Linux-1.3.tar.gz
# 2. Uncompress the file
tar zxf EmojiOneColor-SVGinOT-Linux-1.3.tar.gz
# 3. Run the installer
cd EmojiOneColor-SVGinOT-Linux-1.3
./install.sh
```

Which, hoorah! Enabled me to see colored emojis! ... but also changed the entirety of Firefox to a Serif font.

[image: argh!]

[image: araaaggh!!]

I've checked the Firefox font settings and I'm fairly certain that it's not a bug on Firefox's end.

[image: firefox font settings]

Is there something I can do to sort this out? Or at least figure out what's going on? I actively despise Serif fonts and wish for it to go back to its natural sans-serif form, or at least use the default sans-serif option I gave it.

Comment: Firefox now comes bundled with this font, no need to use fontconfig hacks anymore

Answer (score 1):

The issue is written in their github page 
https://github.com/eosrei/emojione-color-font/

Setting "gfx.font_rendering.fontconfig.fontlist.enabled" on about:config to false solved for me.

[Issue #31] Some font families are not matched correctly in Linux Firefox. Workaround: Open about:config set gfx.font_rendering.fontconfig.fontlist.enabled to false. Note: May cause crashes in Firefox <48